# Alignment of table issue in HTML

Tags: css, html

I want to add 4 tables on my page , two towards left(one above the other) and two towards right(one above the other). Currently I am able to display only two tables towards left alignment but when I am trying towards right alignment property in div as   `<table border="1" style="width:250px" align="right">` I am getting  distortions.  Please find the code as below:-

Can anyone suggest what can be the cause for the issue, I don't want to use CSS but want to accomplish with the alignment property alone.

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" style="width:250px">
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
  <tr><td>India</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Australia</td></tr>
  <tr><td>SouthAfrica</td></tr>
</table>

  <br/><br/><br/><hr size="2"><br/><br/>
  <p><b><u>Countries</u></b> </p> <br/>

<table border="1" style="width:250px" align="left">
  <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
  <tr><td>India</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Australia</td></tr>
  <tr><td>SouthAfrica</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What order should the tables be read in? top left, bottom left, top right, bottom right or top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right? the answer to this will affect the correct answer for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Additionally the table align property is not supported in html5 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_align.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using any alignment property just use tables to make such 4 table alignment.

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <table border="1" style="width:250px">
      <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
      <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
      <tr><td>India</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Australia</td></tr>
      <tr><td>SouthAfrica</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>
    <table border="1" style="width:250px">
      <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
      <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
      <tr><td>India</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Australia</td></tr>
      <tr><td>SouthAfrica</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <table border="1" style="width:250px">
      <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
      <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
      <tr><td>India</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Australia</td></tr>
      <tr><td>SouthAfrica</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>
    <table border="1" style="width:250px">
      <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
      <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
      <tr><td>India</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Australia</td></tr>
      <tr><td>SouthAfrica</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Kr6Q/)

Answer (score 3):

i think this is what you needed. check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DcZrc/1/)

```
<table border="1" width="30%" style="float:left">
```

Comment: Although the op did say they didnt want to use CSS they have inline styles in their example and therefore this is a better result.

Comment: @Mauro in the code given in the question also uses inline css :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<table width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```